# Unable to set UploadedFile object size at runtime in Django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

Reference doc for [UploadedFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/files/uploads/).
Reference for [@fixture](https://pypi.org/project/exam/).
Trying to change the file size in the test case.

```
 from django.core.files.uploadedfile import UploadedFile

 class Mixin(object):
    @fixture
    def photo(self):
        file_obj = StringIO()
        image = Image.new("RGBA", size=(50, 50), color=(256, 0, 0))
        image.save(file_obj, "png")
        file_obj.seek(0)
        return UploadedFile(file_obj, name="test.png", content_type="image/jpg", size=2000000)
```

I tried to change the file size for a test case
`self.photo.size = 10000001`

```
class Test(Mixin):
    @fixture
    def data(self):
        return {"photo": self.photo}

    def test_invalid_photo_size(self):
        self.photo.size = 10000001
        response = self.client.post(reverse("registration_register"), data=self.data)
```

But when I fetch value for the photo in the form, I'm getting the value i.e 144.
`self.cleaned_data.get('photo').size`

It should have returned the 10000001 as size in the form. I'm not clear why this is happening? Any alternative way, other than creating a new photo from scratch.

Comment: some info is missing here. Where is `self.photo` defined? and how does it relate to `self.data`? I don't see how you're submitting the `self.photo`. and where is this `@fixture` decorator defined? which package are you using for that?

Comment: @dirkgroten Updated with the connection between the code.

Comment: You should look at the source of the `fixture` decorator. I haven’t looked at it but since it works similar to a `property` decorator, I don’t think you can change the attributes of objects returned by `fixture` like this. You need to do `photo = self.photo` and then `photo.size = 10000001`, then pass the `photo` explicitly again to `data`. `self.photo.size = 1000001` adds a size attribute to the `photo()` **function** (which is also just an object in python), not to the return value of the function.

Comment: you're right, the fixture returns a pointer to the python object so you can modify its properties.

Comment: I tested you code, the `size` doesn't matter. In fact, when you post a file to your view, only the file itself is used: Django creates a new `UploadedFile` and the size for this comes from the file itself. You could instead of passing an `UploadedFile` to your `post` method just pass you `file_obj`. Even the `size=2000000` when creating the `UploadedFile` gets ignored in my case, where the original file size is `37750`. So you need to change the size of the underlying file if you want to test what happens when submitting a file.

Comment: Are you sure you get 2000000 as size in your view? With your code, I get 144. Also tested `return file_obj` in the `photo` fixture instead of `return UploadedFile()`, it does exactly the same. A browser also doesn't send a `UploadedFile` in a POST, it just sends a file, so Django ignores all the attributes of `UploadedFile` and constructs the request using the file.

Comment: @dirkgroten Then what can I do to test this view?

Comment: Just use a different source file with the size you want.

Comment: I have a folder with lots of photos of different encoding, sizes, aspect ratios and resolutions. Then a function to fetch the right one depending on what I need to test. So don’t use @fixture for this.

Comment: @dirkgroten, One more and last thing. I noticed when I posted file_obj by setting file_obj.name="something.png". I can fetch this value in the form. But file_obj.size=1000. Doesn't work the same way. After all, both are properties for the file.

Comment: No the file name isn’t embedded in the file itself (the byte stream of the content), it’s always an external property. In an HTTP post it’s passes in the header of the multipart part.

Comment: The size is just the number of bytes of the bytestream.